# Mongodb aggregate return if a person belongs to a team

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Team:

```js
const teamSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    trim: true
  },
  owner: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    trim: true
  }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

Member:

```js
const memberSchema = new Schema({
  id_team: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Team',
    required: true
  },
  id_user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: roles,
    default: 'user'
  }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

```js
const id_user = '6eiri59fdd0d8a2jfiff7nfnf'

  return Team.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'members',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'id_team',
        as: 'members'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        name: 1,
        owner: 1,
        description: 1,
        membersCount: { $size: '$members' },
        isUserInTeam: { // <- problem
          $in: [
            id_user,
            '$members.id_user'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]).then((teams) => ({
    count: teams.length,
    rows: teams
  })).then(notFound(res))
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(next)
```

I have the following code should return me if a specific user (`id_user` string type) belongs to a team or not.

But I'm not succeeding, it always comes back false.

I also tried the ways below, but nothing works.

Can you give me a hand?

```js
$in: [
ObjectId(id_user),
ObjectId('$members.id_user')
]

$in: [
new ObjectId(id_user),
new ObjectId('$members.id_user')
]

const objectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId

$in: [
objectId(id_user),
objectId('$members.id_user')
]
```

Comment: just try `isUserInTeam: {  $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id_user), '$members.id_user']}`

Comment: @turivishal: It seems to work, but I'm sure I tried it, it didn't work.